# JWT not included in the POST body

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm currently implementing a Journey Builder custom activity and trying to get the JWT from Marketing Cloud using App Signature encoding as explained in the documentation: [Encode with App Signature](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/encode-custom-activities-using-jwt-app-signature.htm)

The problem is that I don't receive any JWT in the POST request body to any of my application endpoints: `MY_ENDPOINT/save`, `MY_ENDPOINT/edit` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole message is encoded in a JWT and needs to be decoded. You can find a working example of a custom activity, using JWT on my github account:
 [Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Service Cloud Custom Split Activity](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit). I also added the important code for decoding the token below. Another important thing is, that you need to add `"useJwt": true` separately to every route in your activity's `configurationArguments` in `config.json`.

In my repository you can find a utility function I created for decoding the token in `backend/lib/jwt.js`. Furthermore I documented everything needed to setup the custom activity.

**Example of decoding a JWT (assuming you use Node.js and express):**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Register middleware that parses the request payload.
app.use(require('body-parser').raw({
    type: 'application/jwt'
}));

app.post('/activity/execute', (req, res) => {
    require('jsonwebtoken').verify(req.body.toString('utf8'), 'yoursecret', {
        algorithm: 'HS256'
    }, (err, decoded) => {
        // If the token was invalid err is set, otherwise the decoded payload can be found in decoded
    });
});
```

Even though you use app signature, for completeness sake: When using an external key, marketing cloud documentation has one small mistake currently:

According to the documentation the salt key can be converted by piping it to `xxd -p` and adding `0x` as prefix. However in my tests on MacOS and CentOS the last two characters `0a` had to be removed, so I propose to use `echo "Hello world" | xxd -p | sed 's/^/0x/;s/0a$//'` instead, where *Hello world* would be your salt.

Comment: Maybe I'm just a noob here, but I am struggling to get this working, can you comment if this is accurate?
I take the example of the salt "Hello world"
In MC the Salt value i put in would be 0x48656c6c6f20776f726c64 based on what I understood.
In the App I would then put in "Hello world" as the jwt secret.

I have tried testing this and when decoding I get signature verification issue, which is confirmed when I copy the encoded JWT to https://jwt.io/  and put in the Salt "Hello world".

Comment: Also  this was for the /login endpoint for apps, but when I try using it with JB components, none of the calls actualls delivers anything JWT related in req.body despite having it in the config.json file. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Still facing the issue with the Salt being wrong, when using Apps, but the JB component is now working, I forgot to add: 
app.use(bodyparser.raw({type: 'application/jwt'}));